# How to substitude .dll in running lua program

Tags: dll, lua

Lua is able to load .dll dynamically either by using `require`, or by `package.loadlib`. There's however no function to unload the module.

I want to be able to update the module in running program. The program itself would be notified about the new version of the .dll. Then it would load the new one, change the module table and unload the previous one.

I've managed to do it by using some strange code snippet with `unrequire` function, and forcing the garbage collection on code. I'd like to be able to do it in a more civilized way. I know that there are functions `dlclose` and `FreeLibrary`, on windows and linux. There's no way I could call them, though, because I have no access to the actual handle of the library.

The lack of unload function is motivated by the fact, that the lua interpreter can't really know if it won't be using the C functions from the module anymore. This is not the case in my situation, as I'm going only to **update** the library, rather than remove it completely.

Comment: Doesn't this simple `unrequire` work? `function unrequire(m)
 package.loaded[m] = nil
 _G[m] = nil
end
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but there will be limitations to making it work.

The basic idea is to create a layer of indirection between the Lua functions and scripts that `require` and use the module, and the actual C functions that you're trying to change behind the scenes. This is best done in your module *itself*. That is, rather than having Lua code do the replacing of functions and such, have the C functions do the replacing themselves.

That way, you're in control.

The idea is simple. You have two modules: a stub module that is what Lua registers functions for, and the *actual* module with the function implementations. Only the latter module changes.

Your stub module is a Lua module that has two functions that it registers with Lua. The first is a stub function, which it registers multiple times. It is registered as a *closure* with a single upvalue.

That upvalue is a C function. The only thing this stub function does is pull the one upvalue out of the Lua state and call it with the same parameters it was given, returning exactly the values that the function being called returns. It requires a bit of stack finessing to pass-through correctly, but I'll assume you know how to handle that. Also, this function should check the value of the upvalue; if its `nil`, then do nothing and return nothing (this prevents errors).

The second function is something we'll get to in a bit.

Your stub module initialization routine will load your *actual* module, which is really just a DLL. This DLL needs to have a function that will provide a list of functions the actual module exports. Thus, it can query the various Lua functions that are to be forwarded.

For each exported function from the actual module, it registers the stub function with Lua, giving it that name. The upvalue for the stub is set to be the exported function, loaded without upvalues.

Obviously, the handle to the DLL will need to be preserved, likely as a userdata in a registry entry or something.

The second function your stub module exports is the one that will reload the actual module. To do this, you load the new DLL (not unloading the old one first). To make this process robust (despite your assurance that the function lists will be identical. I dislike assuming things like this), you will need to iterate over your module table.

For every registered function that isn't in the new DLL, set it's upvalue to `nil` (and remove them from the module's table). For every registered function that is in the new DLL, change the upvalue to be the new function. If the new DLL has unregistered functions, stick them in the table now by registering the stub function with the new upvalue.

After all of this is done, then you can unload the old DLL.

There; done.

Note: in order for this to work, your module functions must be well-behaved. They can't do things like register other C-functions and so forth. They can't use Lua 5.2's mechanism for yielding and resuming coroutines across C boundaries. And so forth. Otherwise, you run the risk of calling into an unloaded DLL.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! The caveats at the end shouldn't be the problem; the C modules are going to be used only when lua modules would be too slow. I did however notice very interesting possibility here. Do you think you could use the stub module to load any arbitrary .dll/.so + .h, just like LuaJIT's FFI does? I guess you would replace the added "GetFunctionList" with parsed .h file; other than that, the process would be identical. Please, let me know what do you think about that.

Comment: @Bartek: "Do you think you could use the stub module to load any arbitrary .dll/.so + .h, just like LuaJIT's FFI does?" No. Because arbitrary DLLs don't expose *Lua functions*. Remember: you're not calling C functions from the stub; you're calling Lua functions, which just so happen to be written in C. They have a specific signature (`int(lua_State*)`); most DLLs don't expose functions with that signature. FFI is all about automatically creating functions that transform Lua parameters and arguments into C parameters and arguments.

Comment: Hm, that's a good point. If I were to statically prepare the links, though (the stub functions of type `(int(lua_State*))`), using the functions from the library, i should be able to do it, right? I could generate C file from .h pretty easily, I guess. Then I would need to compile this file. I would end with 3 .dlls - the main lua-dll, the linkage between lua-dll and original library, and the original library itself.

Comment: @Bartek: Yes, but you would just be rewriting FFI. And probably not as well, since LuaJIT's FFI likely generates assembly, while yours is entirely static.

Comment: You're of course right. I was asking 1. out of curiosity 2. Because I can use the possibility of doing so in the discussion I'm gonna have. Just proving a point, you see. In production I would certainly stick to Alien or FFI. Thanks again ;)